# How to use make without an install.txt

Tags: java, make

I am trying to install JRE 1.7_67 from the source tarball.

It does not come with an INSTALL file.

How do I compile the package and install it without one?

Comment: Is there a `configure` script? Execute it. Is there a `[Mm]akefile`? Run `make`.

Comment: There is not, here are the contents of the folder. [Screenshot Java Folder](http://www.mediafire.com/view/d95ducf943f8jlo/snapshot1.png)

Comment: If there are no instructions or hints in `README` or `Welcome.html`, you may have an incomplete package.

Comment: Neither file tells me anything, I downloaded it from the official Java download site, I'll try converting the RPM's on their site to install instead of source

Comment: Sure that is a source package? What does `find -maxdepth 2 -type d` list in that dir?

Comment: That does not appear to be a source tarball. FYI there are [online installation instructions at the oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jre.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't a source package, it worked by converting the rpm to a deb installer

Comment: delete {SOLVED} from the title and mark your answer as accepted, click in the checkmark